# Diagnosing the cause of an Android app crashing

Tags: android-studio, debugging, crash

I have been modifying the code of a working Android app.  However, it builds fine but crashes on the test device as soon as it is installed by Android Studio.  In order to try and identify where the problem is, I have commented out chunks of code until I am left with just this uncommented code!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static Context con;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        con = this;

    }

}
```

I have captured what `logcat` has displayed during the time the app was launched.  I clicked delete, started the app and copied the `logcat` window once it had crashed.  This was put into a text editor and the bit below is between the first and last mention of the app name (can you tell - I am not sure how to best use `logcat`!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="8"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Lets Delight Ltd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.461"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.388" />

    <!--<Button
        android:id="@+id/decision"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Download new app"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />-->

    <!--<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/decision"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.799"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_crossed" />-->

    <!--<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="This app is now obsolete\n\nPlease download the replacement using the button below. Then delete this app."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.54" />
-->
    <!--<Button
        android:id="@+id/todo"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="324dp"
        android:text="ToDo LIST"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/decision"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output is at https://www.letsdelight.co.uk/content/temp/logcat_181011.txt because StackOverflow won't let me post that amount of content.

What can I do to try and understand the problem?
Can I use `logcat` in a better way to diagnose the issue or should I be looking at other way to understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Its crashing because of this Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout. Can you post your xml ? and I hope you declared support library dependency 
implement com.android.support:design:'

Comment: I've added the XML to the post - these two declarations are in the gradle file `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` and `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and you need to add this dependency.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0
```

Comment: Since adding this dependency the code is showing an error in the IDE.  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`  -  Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Comment: clean build and make sure you use proper version app support lib version.if your appcompat is 26.1.0 and then use the same version of support design.implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0

Comment: Thanks - I actually worked out that I needed to use 26.1.0 from the IDE messages.  I've done that which has solved the 'R' issue but the app still crashes immediately it is launched...

Comment: My question wasn't so much "what is wrong with my code?" but more "how can I find what is wrong with my code?".  If I can understand the process you went through to answer the problem then I should be able to solve it for myself next time.